# What is the difference between pandas agg and apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I can't figure out the difference between Pandas `.aggregate` and `.apply` functions.
Take the following as an example: I load a dataset, do a `groupby`, define a simple function,
and either user `.agg` or `.apply`.

As you may see, the printing statement within my function results in the same output
after using `.agg` and `.apply`. The result, on the other hand is different. Why is that?

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd
iris = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
by_species = iris.groupby('Species')
def f(x):
    ...:     print type(x)
    ...:     print x.head(3)
    ...:     return 1
```

Using `apply`:

```
by_species.apply(f)
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
#0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
#1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
#2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
#0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
#1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
#2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#    Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width     Species
#50           7.0          3.2           4.7          1.4  versicolor
#51           6.4          3.2           4.5          1.5  versicolor
#52           6.9          3.1           4.9          1.5  versicolor
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#     Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width    Species
#100           6.3          3.3           6.0          2.5  virginica
#101           5.8          2.7           5.1          1.9  virginica
#102           7.1          3.0           5.9          2.1  virginica
#Out[33]: 
#Species
#setosa        1
#versicolor    1
#virginica     1
#dtype: int64
```

Using `agg`

```
by_species.agg(f)
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
#0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
#1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
#2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#    Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width     Species
#50           7.0          3.2           4.7          1.4  versicolor
#51           6.4          3.2           4.5          1.5  versicolor
#52           6.9          3.1           4.9          1.5  versicolor
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#     Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width    Species
#100           6.3          3.3           6.0          2.5  virginica
#101           5.8          2.7           5.1          1.9  virginica
#102           7.1          3.0           5.9          2.1  virginica
#Out[34]: 
#           Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width
#Species                                                         
#setosa                 1            1             1            1
#versicolor             1            1             1            1
#virginica              1            1             1            1
```

Comment: Try typing `help(by_species.agg)` then `help(by_species.apply)` and see what it says.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`apply` applies the function to each group (your `Species`). Your function returns 1, so you end up with 1 value for each of 3 groups.

`agg` aggregates *each column (feature)* for each group, so you end up with one value per column per group.

Do read the [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) docs, they're quite helpful. There are also a bunch of tutorials floating around the web.

Comment: Thus, if I want to use my `func` in the whole groups I should choose `apply`, and if a single `column` in each group, `agg` is a better choice.

Comment: but it seems by_species.apply(sum) still return you each group's columns's sum instead of the sum of the whole sub dataframe in each group

Answer (score 39):

(**Note:** These comparisons are **relevant for DataframeGroupby objects**)

Some plausible **advantages of using `.agg()`** compared to `.apply()`, **for DataFrame GroupBy objects** would be:

1. `.agg()` gives the flexibility of **applying multiple functions at once**, or pass a list of function to each column.
2. Also, **applying different functions at once to different columns of dataframe.**

That means you have pretty much control over each column with each operation.

Here is the link for more details: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/groupby.html

---

However, the `apply` function could be limited to apply one function to each column of the dataframe at a time. So, you might have to call the apply function repeatedly to call upon different operations to the same column.

**Here are some example comparisons for `.apply()` vs `.agg()` for DataframeGroupBy objects :**

Given the following dataframe:

```
In [261]: df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["Foo", "Baar", "Foo", "Baar"], "score_1":[5,10,15,10], "score_2" :[10,15,10,25], "score_3" : [10,20,30,40]})

In [262]: df
Out[262]: 
   name  score_1  score_2  score_3
0   Foo        5       10       10
1  Baar       10       15       20
2   Foo       15       10       30
3  Baar       10       25       40
```

**Lets first see the operations using `.apply()`:**

```
In [263]: df.groupby(["name", "score_1"])["score_2"].apply(lambda x : x.sum())
Out[263]: 
name  score_1
Baar  10         40
Foo   5          10
      15         10
Name: score_2, dtype: int64

In [264]: df.groupby(["name", "score_1"])["score_2"].apply(lambda x : x.min())
Out[264]: 
name  score_1
Baar  10         15
Foo   5          10
      15         10
Name: score_2, dtype: int64

In [265]: df.groupby(["name", "score_1"])["score_2"].apply(lambda x : x.mean())
Out[265]: 
name  score_1
Baar  10         20.0
Foo   5          10.0
      15         10.0
Name: score_2, dtype: float64
```

Now, look at the **same operations using .agg( ) effortlessly:**

```
In [276]: df.groupby(["name", "score_1"]).agg({"score_3" :[np.sum, np.min, np.mean, np.max], "score_2":lambda x : x.mean()})
Out[276]: 
              score_2 score_3               
             <lambda>     sum amin mean amax
name score_1                                
Baar 10            20      60   20   30   40
Foo  5             10      10   10   10   10
     15            10      30   30   30   30
```

---

So, `.agg()` could be really handy at handling the DataFrameGroupBy objects, as compared to `.apply()`. **But, if you are handling only pure dataframe objects and not DataFrameGroupBy objects, then `apply()` can be very useful, as `apply()` can apply a function along any axis of the dataframe.**

**(For Eg: `axis = 0` implies column-wise operation with `.apply(),`** which is a default mode, and **`axis = 1` would imply for row-wise operation while dealing with pure dataframe objects).**

Comment: Also, you can use apply if you need a function to access more than one column at once

Comment: Please note that `agg()` allows you to select an axis as well. The OP probably means that `apply()` provide more flexibility and control when selecting one or more axis.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between apply and aggregate is:

```
apply()- 
    cannot be applied to multiple groups together 
    For apply() - We have to get_group()
    ERROR : -iris.groupby('Species').apply({'Sepal.Length':['min','max'],'Sepal.Width':['mean','min']})# It will throw error
    Work Fine:-iris.groupby('Species').get_group('Setosa').apply({'Sepal.Length':['min','max'],'Sepal.Width':['mean','min']})# It will throw error
        #because functions are applied to one data frame

agg()- 
    can be applied to multiple groups together
    For apply() - We do not have to get_group() 
    iris.groupby('Species').agg({'Sepal.Length':['min','max'],'Sepal.Width':['mean','min']})
    iris.groupby('Species').get_group('versicolor').agg({'Sepal.Length':['min','max'],'Sepal.Width':['mean','min']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) . Let me requote the same statement here

> Some operations on the grouped data might not fit into either the aggregate or transform categories. Or, you may simply want GroupBy to infer how to combine the results. For these, use the apply function, which can be substituted for both aggregate and transform in many standard use cases. However, apply can handle some exceptional use cases, for example:

More details with example are presented in the pandas documentation (link provided above)

Kindly refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object/47143056#47143056) great write up from @ted Petrou and @Eric O Lebigot. We can reapply the logic they have used to investigate difference between Apply and transform to Apply and Agg

Then to understand how axis works refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963927/how-to-dataframe-groupby-along-axis-1)

These three link should help is getting better clarity on how they are different.

Answer (score 0):

When using apply to a groupby I have encountered that `.apply` will return the grouped columns. There is a note in the documentation ([pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)):

> "...Thus the grouped columns(s) may be included in the output as well as set the indices."

`.aggregate` will not return the grouped columns.

Answer (score 0):

Besides everything other mentioned, another difference I think no one highlighted yet is that apply can be used to apply a function to a group of columns together. Agg only applies a function to one column separately. An example is:

Let's use the same example as of other example:

d = pd.DataFrame({"name":["Foo", "Baar", "Foo", "Baar"], "score_1":[5,10,15,10], "score_2" :[10,15,10,25], "score_3" : [10,20,30,40]})

Here, the apply is using a function that sums up the values of all the columns of a group together.

d.groupby(["name", "score_1"]).apply(lambda x: x.values.sum())

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).