# Pandas groupby aggregate passing group name to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In a common usage pattern, I need to aggregate a DataFrame using a custom aggregate function. 
In this special case, the aggregate function needs to know the current group 
in order to correctly perform the aggregation.

A function passed to `DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate()` is called for each group **and** for each column, receiving the Series with the elements in current group and column. 
The only way I found to get the group name from inside the aggregate function is adding the grouping column to the index and then extracting the value with
`x.index.get_level_values('power')[0]`. Here an example:

```
def _tail_mean_user_th(x):
    power = x.index.get_level_values('power')[0]
    th = th_dict[power]  # this values changes with the group
    return x.loc[x > th].mean() - th

mbsize_df = (bursts_sel.set_index('power', append=True).groupby('power')
             .agg({'nt': _tail_mean_user_th}))
```

It seems to me that it is a pretty common occurrence that the aggregate function needs to know the current group. Is there a more straightforward pattern in this  situation?

---

**EDIT**: The solution that I accepted below consists in using `apply` instead of `agg` on the GroupBy object. The difference between the two is that `agg` calls the function for each group and each column separately, while `apply` calls the function for each group (all columns at once). A subtle consequence of this is that `agg` will pass a `Series` for current group and column with its `name` attribute equal to the original column name. Conversely, `apply` will pass a `Series` with a `name` attribute equal to the current group (which was my question). Interestingly, when operating on multiple columns, `apply` will pass a DataFrame with a `name` attribute (normally non-existent for DataFrames) set to the group name. So this pattern also works when aggregating multiple columns at once.

For more info see [What is the difference between pandas agg and apply function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828398/what-is-the-difference-between-pandas-agg-and-apply-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: If you add `as_index=False` to the `groupby`, is the `power` column available directly as an attribute of `x`?

Comment: @scnerd, `as_index` controls the index of the returned dataframe after aggregation, not the index seen by the function called through `.agg`. I want `as_index=True` in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use `groupby` + `apply`, then it is available through the `.name` attribute:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'b': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
def foo(g):
    print('at group %s' % g.name)
    return int(g.name) + g.sum()    

>>> df.b.groupby(df.a).apply(foo)
at group 1
at group 2
a
1    4
2    5
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I my feeling "there must be a better way" was right.