# Pandas groupby.apply tries to preserve the original dataframe strucutre

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
In [11]: import numpy as np
    ...: import pandas as pd
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(10,10)), index=range(10), columns=range(10))
    ...: cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['m', 'n']], names=['l1', 'l2'])
    ...: df.columns = cols

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
l1         a                   b                   c                   d                   e
l2         m         n         m         n         m         n         m         n         m         n
0   0.257448  0.207198  0.443456  0.553674  0.765539  0.428972  0.587296  0.942761  0.115083  0.073907
1   0.099647  0.702320  0.792053  0.409488  0.112574  0.435044  0.767640  0.946108  0.257002  0.286178
2   0.110061  0.058266  0.350634  0.657057  0.900674  0.882870  0.250355  0.861289  0.041383  0.981890
3   0.408866  0.042692  0.726473  0.482945  0.030925  0.337217  0.377866  0.095778  0.033939  0.550848
4   0.255034  0.455349  0.193223  0.377962  0.445834  0.400846  0.725098  0.567926  0.052293  0.471593
5   0.133966  0.239252  0.479669  0.678660  0.146475  0.042264  0.929615  0.873308  0.603774  0.788071
6   0.068064  0.849320  0.786785  0.767797  0.534253  0.348995  0.267851  0.838200  0.351832  0.566974
7   0.240924  0.089154  0.161263  0.179304  0.077933  0.846366  0.916394  0.771528  0.798970  0.942207
8   0.808719  0.737900  0.300483  0.205682  0.073342  0.081998  0.002116  0.550923  0.460010  0.650109
9   0.413887  0.671698  0.294521  0.833841  0.002094  0.363820  0.148294  0.632994  0.278557  0.340835
```

And then I want to do the following `groupby-apply` operation.

```
In [17]: def func(df):
    ...:     return df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values('l2') == 'm']
    ...:
In [19]: df.groupby(level='l1', axis=1).apply(func)
Out[19]:
l1         a             b             c             d             e
l2         m   n         m   n         m   n         m   n         m   n
0   0.257448 NaN  0.443456 NaN  0.765539 NaN  0.587296 NaN  0.115083 NaN
1   0.099647 NaN  0.792053 NaN  0.112574 NaN  0.767640 NaN  0.257002 NaN
2   0.110061 NaN  0.350634 NaN  0.900674 NaN  0.250355 NaN  0.041383 NaN
3   0.408866 NaN  0.726473 NaN  0.030925 NaN  0.377866 NaN  0.033939 NaN
4   0.255034 NaN  0.193223 NaN  0.445834 NaN  0.725098 NaN  0.052293 NaN
5   0.133966 NaN  0.479669 NaN  0.146475 NaN  0.929615 NaN  0.603774 NaN
6   0.068064 NaN  0.786785 NaN  0.534253 NaN  0.267851 NaN  0.351832 NaN
7   0.240924 NaN  0.161263 NaN  0.077933 NaN  0.916394 NaN  0.798970 NaN
8   0.808719 NaN  0.300483 NaN  0.073342 NaN  0.002116 NaN  0.460010 NaN
9   0.413887 NaN  0.294521 NaN  0.002094 NaN  0.148294 NaN  0.278557 NaN
```

Notice that even if I do not retun any data for columns with `l2=='n'`, the structure of the original dataframe is still preserved and pandas automatically fill in the values with `nan`.

This is a simplified example, my intention here is not to select out the `'m'` columns, this example is just for a illustration of the problem I am facing -- I want to apply some function on some subset of the columns in the dataframe and the result dataframe should only have the columns I care about.

Also I noticed that you cannot rename the column in the apply function. For example if you do:

```
In [25]: def func(df):
    ...:     df = df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values('l2') == 'm']
    ...:     df = df.rename(columns={'m':'p'}, level=1)
    ...:     return df
    ...:

In [26]: df.groupby(level='l1', axis=1).apply(func)
Out[26]:
l1   a       b       c       d       e
l2   m   n   m   n   m   n   m   n   m   n
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Notice the result is full of `NaN` but the original format of the DF is preserved.

My question is, what should I do so that in the applied function I can manipulate the df so the output of the apply can be different in shape compared to the original df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read ["What is the difference between pandas agg and apply function?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21831599/7725670). Depending on your actual use case, you may not need to change the function being passed into `.agg` or `.apply`.

> I want to apply some function on some subset of the columns in the dataframe

You can shape the DataFrame before grouping, or return only a subset of e.g. columns with the desired aggregation or function application.

```py
# pass an indexed view
grouped0 = df.loc[:, ['a', 'b', 'c'].groupby(level='l1', axis=1)

# perform the .agg or .apply on a subset of e.g. columns
result1 = df.groupby(level='l1', axis=1)['a', 'b', 'c'].agg(np.sum)
```

Using `.agg` on your example code:

```py
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
l1         a                   b            ...         d                   e
l2         m         n         m         n  ...         m         n         m         n
0   0.007932  0.697320  0.181242  0.380013  ...  0.075391  0.820732  0.335901  0.808365
1   0.736584  0.621418  0.736926  0.962414  ...  0.331465  0.711948  0.426704  0.849730
2   0.099217  0.802882  0.082109  0.489288  ...  0.758056  0.627021  0.539329  0.808187
3   0.152319  0.378918  0.205193  0.489060  ...  0.337615  0.475191  0.025432  0.616413
4   0.582070  0.709464  0.739957  0.472041  ...  0.299662  0.151314  0.113506  0.504926
5   0.351747  0.480518  0.424127  0.364428  ...  0.267780  0.092946  0.134434  0.443320
6   0.572375  0.157129  0.582345  0.124572  ...  0.074523  0.421519  0.733218  0.079004
7   0.026940  0.762937  0.108213  0.073087  ...  0.758596  0.559506  0.601568  0.603528
8   0.991940  0.864772  0.759207  0.523460  ...  0.981770  0.332174  0.012079  0.034952

In [4]: df.groupby(level='l1', axis=1).sum()
Out[4]:
l1         a         b         c         d         e
0   0.705252  0.561255  0.804299  0.896123  1.144266
1   1.358002  1.699341  1.422559  1.043413  1.276435
2   0.902099  0.571397  0.273161  1.385077  1.347516
3   0.531237  0.694253  0.914989  0.812806  0.641845
4   1.291534  1.211998  1.138044  0.450976  0.618433
5   0.832265  0.788555  1.063437  0.360726  0.577754
6   0.729504  0.706917  1.018795  0.496042  0.812222
7   0.789877  0.181300  0.406009  1.318102  1.205095
8   1.856713  1.282666  1.183835  1.313944  0.047031
9   0.273369  0.391189  0.867865  0.978350  0.654145

In [10]: df.groupby(level='l1', axis=1).agg(lambda x: x[0])
Out[10]:
l1         a         b         c         d         e
0   0.007932  0.181242  0.708712  0.075391  0.335901
1   0.736584  0.736926  0.476286  0.331465  0.426704
2   0.099217  0.082109  0.037351  0.758056  0.539329
3   0.152319  0.205193  0.419761  0.337615  0.025432
4   0.582070  0.739957  0.279153  0.299662  0.113506
5   0.351747  0.424127  0.845485  0.267780  0.134434
6   0.572375  0.582345  0.309942  0.074523  0.733218
7   0.026940  0.108213  0.084424  0.758596  0.601568
8   0.991940  0.759207  0.412974  0.981770  0.012079
9   0.045315  0.282569  0.019320  0.638741  0.292028

In [11]: df.groupby(level='l1', axis=1).agg(lambda x: x[1])
Out[11]:
l1         a         b         c         d         e
0   0.697320  0.380013  0.095587  0.820732  0.808365
1   0.621418  0.962414  0.946274  0.711948  0.849730
2   0.802882  0.489288  0.235810  0.627021  0.808187
3   0.378918  0.489060  0.495227  0.475191  0.616413
4   0.709464  0.472041  0.858891  0.151314  0.504926
5   0.480518  0.364428  0.217953  0.092946  0.443320
6   0.157129  0.124572  0.708853  0.421519  0.079004
7   0.762937  0.073087  0.321585  0.559506  0.603528
8   0.864772  0.523460  0.770861  0.332174  0.034952
9   0.228054  0.108620  0.848545  0.339609  0.362117
```

Since you say that your example `func` is not your use case, please provide an example of your specific use case if the general cases don't fit.