# Pandas Date Groupby & Apply - performance improvement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm doing a half-hourly date groupby and apply to calculate daily statistics on my dataset, but it's slow. Is there a way to improve the performance of the following functions? I've read about vectorisation, but am unsure how to implement it.

I've used apply and transform to get the outputs I would like, but it takes about 2-3 seconds for a whole year worth of data, I hope to do it faster as I have a lot data. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit

# dummy data
date_range = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00', freq='30Min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, 20, (date_range.shape[0], 2)), index=date_range, columns=['Electricity', 'Natural Gas'])

print(df.head())
print(df.shape)

t1 = timeit.default_timer()
onhour = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D')]).apply(lambda x: np.count_nonzero(
    x[x > x.quantile(0.05) + x.mean() * .1] >
    x.quantile(0.05) + 0.25 * (x.quantile(0.95)-x.quantile(0.05)),
    axis=0) / 2)

onhour = pd.DataFrame(
    onhour.values.tolist(),
    index=onhour.index,
    columns=df.columns)

print(f"start_time in {timeit.default_timer() - t1}")
print(onhour.head())

t1 = timeit.default_timer()
onhour = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D')]).transform(lambda x: np.count_nonzero(
    x[x > x.quantile(0.05) + x.mean() * .1] >
    x.quantile(0.05) + 0.25 * (x.quantile(0.95)-x.quantile(0.05)),
    axis=0) / 2).resample('D').mean()

print(f"start_time in {timeit.default_timer() - t1}")
print(onhour.head())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using pandas vectorization optimization, so you can't gain a lot of time but a few tricks can get you in the 1.5 sec.

1) Use agg

Using `agg` instead of `transform` or `apply` will give better result because [you have the same computation for each column (electricity & gas)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21831599/3933052).

2) save your quantiles computations.

You are calculating 3 times the 5% quantile. I used a python `function` instead of `lambda`, you could still use lambda if you add a memoized quantile function (it could actually help fasten but I'm sure).

```
def count_something(row):
    qt_df = row.quantile([0.05, 0.95])
    return np.count_nonzero(
        row[row > qt_df.loc[0.05] + row.mean() * .1] > qt_df.loc[0.05] + 0.25 * (qt_df.loc[0.95] - qt_df.loc[0.05]),
        axis=0) / 2

t1 = timeit.default_timer()

onhour = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D')]).agg(count_something)

print(f"start_time in {timeit.default_timer() - t1}")
print(onhour.head())
```

If you really want to quicken the computation and you have ways to parralelize or distribute your computation, I imagine you could use [python dask](https://dask.org/) but I don't how much it could improve your problem.

Comment: Ah yes, perfect. This shaves of a good bit of time in total. There may be scope for dask in the future! Using lambda instead of a function seems to be marginally faster.

Comment: I also tried to see if calculating the median (50% quantile) was faster than the mean - as it's a quite good approximation with unskewed data. To my surprise, it does not seem to be quicker but i didn't do robust test...