# How can I keep all rows of a grouped pandas DataFrage meeting a certain criteria?

Tags: python-3.x, search, indexing, pandas-groupby, rows

For a pandas DataFrame with groups I want to keep all rows until the first occurence of a specific value (and discard all other rows).

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'tmp'],
                   'B' : [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   'C' : [2.0, 5., 8., 1., 2., 9., 7.]})
```

gives

```
    A    B  C
0   foo  0  2.0
1   foo  1  5.0
2   foo  0  8.0
3   bar  0  1.0
4   bar  0  2.0
5   bar  1  9.0
6   tmp  0  7.0
```

and I want to keep all rows for each group (`A` is the grouping variable) until `B == 1` (including this row). So, my desired output is

```
    A    B  C
0   foo  0  2.0
1   foo  1  5.0
3   bar  0  1.0
4   bar  0  2.0
5   bar  1  9.0
6   tmp  0  7.0
```

**How can I keep all rows of a grouped DataFrage meeting a certain criteria?**

I found [how to drop specific groups not meeting a certain criteria (and keeping all other rows of all other groups)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html), but not how to drop specific rows for all groups. The farest I got was to get the indices of the rows in each group, I want to keep:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['B'].cumsum().searchsorted(1))
```

resulting in

```
A
bar    2
foo    1
tmp    1
```

Which isn't sufficient, as it does not return the actual data (and it might be better, if for `tmp` the result was `0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21828398/6256241) about the difference between `groupby.apply` and `groupby.aggregate`, I realized that `apply` works on all columns and rows (thus a DataFrame?) of the group. So this is my function that should be applied on every group:

```
def f(group):
    index = min(group['B'].cumsum().searchsorted(1), len(group))
    return group.iloc[0:index+1]
```

By running `df.groupby('A').apply(f)` I get the desired result:

```
            A       B   C
A               
bar     3   bar     0   1.0
        4   bar     0   2.0
        5   bar     1   9.0
foo     0   foo     0   2.0
        1   foo     1   5.0
tmp     6   tmp     0   7.0
```