# How apply is able to reduce a group?

Tags: pandas

I found some interseting questions here in Stack Overflow like this ([What is the difference between pandas agg and apply function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828398/what-is-the-difference-between-pandas-agg-and-apply-function)) but I still can't understand how `apply` can sometimes behaves like `agg`. Also, how `transform` treats the groups ? Sorry guys if these are some stupid questions to ask in 2023 but I'll be more than happy if someone can explain clearly and straight to the point how each of the three functions below behave.

```
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'Value': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df.groupby('Category').agg({'Value': 'mean'})
df2 = df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.mean())
df3 = df.groupby('Category')['Value'].transform('mean').to_frame()

print(f'{df1=}', f'{df2=}', f'{df3=}', sep='\n\n')

df1=           Value
Category        
A        18.3333
B        26.6667

df2=           Value
Category        
A        18.3333
B        26.6667

df3=    Value
0 18.3333
1 18.3333
2 26.6667
3 26.6667
4 18.3333
5 26.6667
```

Comment: Kindly have a look at pandas docs, it explains these functions quite well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) creates a unique value for each group (per column) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) creates a Series of the same shape as the input.

On the other side, [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) is fully flexible, it can return an aggregation, a transformation or something else.

For example, let's return a new DataFrame that has nothing to do with the input:

```
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

Output:

```
            0  1
Category        
A        0  1  2
         1  3  4
B        0  1  2
         1  3  4
```

An aggregation:

```
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: 'a' if x.name == 'A' else 'b')

Category
A    a
B    b
dtype: object
```

A transformation:

```
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x+1)

            Value
Category         
A        0     11
         1     16
         4     31
B        2     21
         3     26
         5     36
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. If it was up to me, I would reverse the naming of `apply` and `transform`. Have a nice day.